# custom value in external list

Tags: external-list

I currently have a external list with a column valued either 0, 1 or -1. I want to display different pictures for each value (like a status indicator). Is it possible to do so in SharePoint?

I'm using `SharePoint2010`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a status indicator which an item in Status list. You can create status list using the following 2 options:

option 1: Create just a status list, after status list has been created then add indicators to the list.

Option 2: Create web part with Status list. This is a webpart which builds in A Status list automatically, so that all you need to do is add indicators. Then you can easily use the web part on a dashboard and other web page

Hope it help.

The following link is using javascript to display the indicator:
http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/04/01/add-task-status-indicators-in-sharepoint-2013-using-js-link/

Creating Custom SharePoint 2010 Field Types
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg132914.aspx

Comment: I'm very new to SharePoint. Can you explain in more detail? I tried making a status list based on the external list I have, but all it does is creating a single row indicating how many of the entire list is 0. I want one indicator for each row in my external list. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Hi Tengyu. Please refer for this link. It might help you to proceed with your requirement: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2163/status-list-in-sharepoint-2010